# Webform Submit Button acting like Reset button

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-webform

We set up a simple webform on Drupal:

http://www.example.com/page

Some users are able to submit it without any issues while for others, the form resets when they click submit. There is no clear correlation, one user used: IE9 and Windows 7 which we tested, and are able to submit without any issues, but that user is not, regardless of multiple attempts.

We are using the 6.x-3.14 drupal webform module in case that information is relevant.

We've already tried disabling javascript, and that hasn't solved the problem. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have the code "form action="/volunteer-day-in-the-life"..." Without screwing up your page by submitting bogus information, could you explain where you end up when the form is submitted successfully? Is it possible the data is being input but the user is just being sent back to that page as if it were refreshed/reloaded or is the content lost entirely?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the settings on the module.

```
<form action="/volunteer-day-in-the-life"  accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" id="webform-client-form-19740" class="webform-client-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

The form action should not be the origin of the page, it is just submitting to itself. I'm not sure how you could have successful posts, I broke it right away.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I'm not sure exactly where and which settings to change on the module? Can you clarify how I would change these settings, I don't see an option to do this in he webform module settings.